# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python

Tags: python

I am trying to include the year to `url`. I get syntax is invalid. How can I include the year in my URL.

```
year, month, day, hour = time_point.asStrTuple()
if analysis:
    url = fileinfo['url_anl']
else:
    url = fileinfo['url_fct']

Year = year
year_month = year + month
year_month_day = year_month + day
year_month_day_hour = year_month + day + hour
url += Year + '/' year_month + '/' + year_month_day + '/' + year_month_day_hour + '/'

if analysis:
    url += fileinfo['filecode_anl']
else:
    url += fileinfo['filecode_fct']
url += year_month_day + '_'
```

Comment: Forgotten `+` `url += Year + '/' + year_month + ...`

Comment: `'/' year_month` -- Are you missing a `+`?

Comment: Even after I add + url += Year + '/' + year_month +  the error is still same syntax error

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: @HeshamAttia: Your pending edit contains the fix for the problem (which is also why it's an invalid edit :P)

Comment: @AngelaElorence: You made the same error multiple times on that line. Fix all instances of it.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: This line url += Year + '/' year_month + '/' + year_month_day + '/'year_month_day_hour + '/' @HeshamAttia

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
url += Year + '/' + year_month + '/' + year_month_day + '/' + year_month_day_hour + '/'
```

You forgot `+` two times:

```
'/' year_month 
'/'year_month_day_hour
```

But if you are doing string manipulation it is better to use `format`
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

```
url += '{}/{}/{}/{}/'.format(Year, year_month, year_month_day, year_month_day_hour)
```

Or in your case you can do this with `join` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

```
url += '/'.join([Year, year_month, year_month_day, year_month_day_hour, ''])
```

Note that for join I added `''` empty string to list, so that there will be ending `/`